# Repeat last search in one keystroke?

Tags: vim, neovim

In vim I can begin a search for 'doc', say, by typing `/doc` then ENTER

To repeat that search, I know I can type `/` then ENTER (2 keystrokes)

My question is, can I repeat the search in just one keystroke ?

In notepad you can, albeit with a repeat left mouse click.

I find this ability very handy with SHIFT-# or SHIFT-* for instance, but these only works for a whole word.

Comment: The answer is a few lines below `:help /`. Try harder next time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with `n`. `N` to go backwards.

Comment: As a complementary tip you call show at once all lines that have a pattern typing `:g/pattern/#`